# Mongoose properties are Documents instance instead of plain values

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

Recently I've noticed that mongoose changed behavior.
Whenever I try to access built in string methods of my properties, get an error **undefined is not a function** error.

I am using `@nestjs/mongoose` package, however little debug shows that it passes porperty options correctly.

For example in the below code, property roles handled correctly and I can use it as `Array`. but if I try to access `firstname`, I will get `Document` instead of plain string. Only when I change
`firstname` to `String` it will take effect.

```
@Schema({
  minimize: false,
  timestamps: true,
  toObject: {
    virtuals: true,
  },
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true,
  },
})
export class User {
  _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop({ trim: true })
  firstname: string;

  @Prop({ trim: true })
  lastname: string;

  @Prop({
    trim: true,
    default: 'friend',
  })
  name: string;

  @Prop({
    trim: true,
    sparse: true,
    unique: true,
  })
  username: string;

  @Prop({
    unique: true,
    sparse: true,
    trim: true,
    set: (v) => v?.toLowerCase(),
  })
  email: string;

  @Prop([String])
  roles: Role[];
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

If we look at VSCode we can see that properties in fact are instances of `mongoose.Document`. So I would like to know how it's possible to solve the issue, as I can't lean all my models throughout the code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use lean method provided by mongoose.

Here is an example of how to use it

```
const users = await UserModel.find().lean();
```

Check [this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html) out for more details.